# IBM MobileFirst SSO not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, single-sign-on

I have two apps on my emulator device that go against the same `SecurityCheck` adapter for authentication. I can successfully login from both my apps. But my SSO is not working. If I login from my first app and after that I open the second app, the second app still requires login...vice versa

I have the steps explained in this tutorial:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/device-sso/

Comment: Do you see same  device Id from both apps in console ?

Comment: Yes both apps are on same device id's in mfp console

Comment: I tried it works fine .Just increase successStateExpirationSec value to some higher value

Comment: I increased to 300. But still no success. I have developed these two apps: https://github.com/IBM/Ionic-MFP-App/blob/master/DETAILED.md#step-1-setup-ionic-and-mfp-cli and https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/RememberMeAndroid

Comment: I tried these 
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/RememberMeCordova/tree/release80 and https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/RememberMeAndroid/tree/release80

Comment: When I run the `RememberCordova` app, I only see a blank screen wit the title "Remember Me"

Comment: Are you following these steps :
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp`
`cordova platform add `
`mfpdev app register
`cordova prepare `

?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169683/discussion-between-manjunath-kallannavar-and-farahm).